# Automatic lowercase in a list

Tags: lists, capitalization

I believe this is a very simple question to which there may be a very simple answer that so far I haven't been able to find: How can the text for each item within a regular `LaTeX2e` list (such as `enumerate`) be forced to be typeset as all-lowercase? My problem with this is that `\lowercase` or `\MakeLowercase` are commands requiring a delimited argument, which is not the case with an `\item`, since it works as a control sequence. My motivation: sometimes I'd like to have the text in a list of items to be typeset as small-caps, and have all of the characters corresponding to the lowercase heights, but I'd like to be able to do so without having to use the above commands on a *manual* per-item basis. The most trivial answer (just enter the text in all-lowercase) does not make for a useful answer, since I'd like to be able to use the same text, without needing to retype it, as regular `\upshape` text.

EDIT: I have ticked A. Ellett's proposal as the answer on the basis of its functionality fitting my question and because I think of it as a worthy and very well thought-out contribution on its own terms. Nonetheless, a more simple approach, if feasible, would still be welcome.

Comment: I suppose one way would be to create a font variant that is all lower cased, so that an "A" or "a" would both render with the glyph for "a".  Someone else would have to say how that is done, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This updated version (see revision history for older versions) does not require the user to add any features to their environment.  No need for `\item*` or anything like that.  This is made possible by smuggling in an `\item` on the first iteration and then *shifting* (redefining *again*) `\item`.  I've add extensive comments which should allow you to modify this code to better suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter

%% We will use two versions for redefining \item                       
%% The first version is temporary and only used                        
%% for the first iteration.  It's purpose is to                        
%% allow us to slip in an \item just before the                        
%% environment is ended.                                               
\def\@ae@item@va@#1\item#2\@nil{%%
  \def\item##1\end{\@ae@item@vb@##1\@nil}%%
  \@ae@item@vb@#1\item#2\@nil}

\def\@ae@item@vb@#1\item#2\@nil{%%
  %% Don't immediately pass to \olditem                                
  %% we need to see whether there's any optional                       
  %% arguments being passed to \item                                   
  \ae@olditem #1\@nil%%
  %% If second argument is empty, then that means                      
  %% we've parsed the entire environment and should                    
  %% quit.  Restore the "\end" we stole earlier.                       
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\end
  \else
    %% We don't want to get too deeply buried within                   
    %% \if...\fi structures.  So save #2 to a macro                    
    %% then call a dummy macro, but only after first                   
    %% leaving the \if...\fi structure.                                
    \def\ae@tmp{#2}%%
    \expandafter\@@ae@continue@iterating@item
  \fi}

%% Test whether there's an optional argument.                          
\def\ae@olditem{%%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\@o@ae@olditem}
    {\@@ae@olditem}}
\def\@o@ae@olditem[#1]{\olditem[#1] \@@ae@@format}
\def\@@ae@olditem{\olditem \@@ae@@format}
%% The actual formatting of the content following \item
\def\@@ae@@format#1\@nil{%%
  \bgroup\scshape\lowercase{#1}\egroup}
%% The macro handling the continuation of iterating over               
%% the \item's in the environment.  Notice the use of                  
%% \expandafter.  We don't want to pass the formatting                 
%% macro content buried into a temporary macro.  Remember              
%% the \ae@tmp was only used to help us jump out of the                
%% \if ... \fi structure.                                              
\def\@@ae@continue@iterating@item{%%
  \expandafter\item\ae@tmp\end}

\newenvironment{mylc}
  {%%
    \begin{enumerate}
    \let\olditem\item
    %% new definition for \item but only good for first iteration.     
    %% This is how we smuggle in a final \item                         
    %% just before ending the environment.  Here we                    
    %% also steal the `\end` which closes the environment.             
    %% We'll have to restore that before we're done.                   
    \def\item##1\end{%%
      \@ae@item@va@##1\item\@nil}
  }
  {\end{enumerate}}

\makeatother
\def\aerandomstuff{A random string of stuff.}
\begin{document}

  \begin{mylc}
  \item  `A' is for Amy who\ldots
  \item[<optional argument>] This line has an optional argument.
  \item  
  \item  The previous item was empty, but that won't cause us to
         prematurely terminate.
  \item  Matter buried in a macro will not be handled correctly: \aerandomstuff
  \item  This is the last line. No special mark up needed.
  \end{mylc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding expansion issues:
The `\lowercase` only works upon expanded content.  Anything smuggled in, as I do with `\aerandomstuff` will not first be set in lower case.

Comment: Wow! (Your pardon). I was thinking of something easier than that. It is recomforting to my own self-esteem that we have to get into so much trouble for what I thought was a simple task to which I didn't see an easy answer. Although getting the first character in the item's content would suffice for my own particular current needs, I'd like to be able to grab the entire content if I so wished -- which is what you are considering here. I'm using the `enumitem` pkg. Do you think that something less cumbersome could be done on that basis? Or maybe on an `expl3` basis?

Comment: @Marcos I've updated my answer once again.  This time it works a bit better in the sense that the user doesn't have to use any special mark up to indicate the last item to be processed.